# I am getting an error in android studio. language java, using latest bumblebee android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

I am getting this error in Android studio

> Target API level '30' is out of range ('11' - '24')

My build.gradle contains

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.cts_camera"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
      /*  renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true*/
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

- I have tried invalidate and cache option.
- Also I tried to upgrade the gradle.
- I am using a library that requires minSDK to be 30 and when I make the changes the above error comes up.

how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Update the compile SDK to 32.
API level 32 is the latest compiled SDK version.

Comment: You don't think. It _is_ 32

Comment: Let me know if it fixed the problem